# How to search google with chrome using webbrowser?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I can search google, but it comes up in firefox and I want to open it in chrome.
Can someone help?  This is my code:

```
import webbrowser

new = 2

tabUrl = "https://www.google.com/#safe=strict&q=";

term = raw_input("Enter search query:  ");

webbrowser.open(tabUrl+term,new=new);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to go. The main additional steps seem to be to `register` and `get`.

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('chrome'), 1)
>>> webbrowser.get('chrome')
<webbrowser.GenericBrowser object at 0x00000000064D4128>
>>> tabUrl = "https://www.google.com/#safe=strict&q=";
>>> term='python'
>>> webbrowser.open(tabUrl+term)
True
```

Comment: One question, your 4th line comes back as a syntax error.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest. I've just re-executed these lines twice, once as a batch and again in interactive mode. They worked both times. Would you please check what you've entered.